# Surname - Cast/Ethnicity Mapping for Nepali Names

Tags: census, names, asia

I'm trying to link family names to ethnicity / casts in the Nepali context. Is anyone aware of a publicly accessible data set that would allow or simplify such a mapping?

Example of what the outcome should be (based on manual coding):

[image]

Any micro-data that would allow to construct such a thing, or a ready-made (even partial) mapping would help.

Comment: Ethic group for 14 most popular surnames: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popular_surnames_in_Nepal

Comment: Okay, that's  a good start, but I'd need a rather complete list. At least covering the 80% most common names

Comment: Is there a way to find out how and by whom that list was created? It seems that whoever made this has the information I'm after

Answer (score 2):

This unofficial blog has the top names per group (16 Newar, 15 Khas- Chhetri/Thakuri/Sanyasi, 15 Khas-Brahmin, 5 Tamang, 5 Magar)

https://nepalfederalismdebate.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/most-common-nepali-surnames/

The comments include more info.

---

If you search for individual group, you can find more names. For example:

http://www.gundrukpost.com/newars-have-more-than-115-surnames-how-many-of-them-you-know/